# We know that HashSet internally work as HashMap so while printing Hashset Object why element comes in array?

Tags: java

```
HashSet prime=new HashSet();    // I have created HashSet Object in eclipse IDE
System.out.println(prime);           //As I am getting [] though HashSet internally work as HashMap data structure;
```

Why does it not comes in curly braces `{}`

Comment: That's just an internal representation as the result of the `toString` method, it means nothing.

Comment: It's _internal_ because all the methods, including toString, are implemented on top of that API to hide those details.

Answer (score 2):

[`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) inherits [`AbstractCollection.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--):

> The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("`[]`")

Should it have been implemented originally to use `{}`? Perhaps. Can it be changed without breaking backwards compatibility? No.

Ultimately, you aren't going to satisfy everybody whatever format was chosen. If you want it in a particular format, you should print it in that format, for example:

```
prime.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(joining(", ", "{", "}"))
```

(although you'd need to make `prime` non-raw for that to compile).